# Is there another term for sharing knowledge

Tags: phrase-requests

Hello I am looking for a word that would best be used as an exchange of knowledge or teachings within a community. Is there a word or phrase that would best sum up a group of people who are sharing their knowledge or talents to others?

Comment: You're going to have to show some research for this and explain why simple words like *teachers* (use a thesaurus) don't meet your need.

Comment: "Educators" is the term I would use.

Answer (score 3):

**Disseminators**

> **Disseminate** *verb*: 3rd person present: disseminates; past tense: disseminated; past participle: disseminated; gerund or present participle: disseminating
>
> spread or disperse (something, *especially information*) widely.
>   "health authorities should foster good practice by *disseminating* information"
>
> *synonyms*: spread, circulate, distribute, disperse, promulgate, propagate, publicize, communicate, pass on, put about, make known. See, Google.com [**Link**](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=disseminate+definition&oq=disseminate+definition&gs_l=serp.1.0.0i67j0i7i30l7j0i7i10i30j0.13573.18239.0.23187.2.2.0.0.0.0.148.250.0j2.2.0.msedr...0...1c.1.62.serp..0.2.246.UKdn70FDF5I)
>
> **Dissemination** *noun*; plural noun: disseminations:
>
> the act of spreading something, especially information, widely; circulation.
>   "*dissemination* of public information"

**Promulgators**

> **Promulgate** *verb* (used with object), promulgated, promulgating.
>
> **1**. to make known by open declaration; publish; proclaim formally or put into operation (a law, decree of a court, etc.).
>
> **2**. to set forth or teach publicly (a creed, doctrine, etc.).
>
> See, Google.com [**Link**](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=define+promulgate&sa=X&ei=XWvvVKrxDNCJNpaYgMAG&ved=0CCQQ_SowAA&biw=1024&bih=528)

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the fuller context, perhaps "league" or "syndicate"

Comment: Could the downvoters please explain?